# React Native - Screen not re-rendering when redux state changes

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have a class (a component that creates a screen) called 'Search' in a file called 'Search.js'.

'Search' contains a custom component called 'MyFlatList' that is a child of the 'Search' class.

```
<MyFlatList/>
```

I pass state called 'activeUsersObject' into 'MyFlatList' using Redux

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  activeUsersObject: state.profile.activeUsers,
});
```

I assumed that each time I updated state.activeUsers within redux state.....the 'MyFlatList' child component would try to rerender.....but its not.

Any idea why?  Thanks

EDIT - even stranger is that when activeUsersObject changes from an empty object ({}) to an object with something in it, MyFlatList re-renders....however when it goes the other way round (from populated object to empty) it does not re-render

Comment: how do you change the state?

Comment: updates in firebase trigger action creator

Comment: one of the crucial parts of your code here (which is missing) would be your reducer - depending on implementation, you may unintentionally mutate some part of your global state, thus keeping object reference untouched and your component not re-rendered (as @YogeshSharma suspected)

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to post a comment here, so trying to answer this.
Just make sure, whenever there is change in active users, you are creating a new object. If you change within same object, then it will not re-render